# Can I safely rely on column name case in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, case-sensitive

I want to name my mysql table column names using camel case and create php classes from these mysql tables with the same camel case names.  I will be generating these php classes automatically.  I'm wondering if I can rely on column name case no matter what platform I run my application on.  So for example, if I name one column name "FirstName", will I ever encounter a time where reading the column name from the database will product "firstname" or something like that?

Comment: If you ever port to a different RDBMS, you won't be able to rely on column name case.

Comment: You might want to do what Doctrine does - automatically from camel-cased classes to underscore-separated tables (eg class SomeModelName -> table some_model_name).

Comment: tables are not an issue.  only column names.

Comment: @PaulTomblin, If you ever port to a different RDBMS, column name case would be the least of your concerns. There's more things that you'll need to change.

Comment: @Pacerier that's why I hate MySQL.

Comment: @PaulTomblin, Wait wait, I'm saying about RDBMS in general. Indeed you would hardly find any two db whereby you can just "hot swap" without changing any code and expecting everything to work **identically**. Nothing to do with MySQL.

Comment: @Pacerier my experience is that if you stick to things in the SQL standard, code ports pretty easily between PostgreSQL, Oracle and Sybase, but MySQL is a dogs breakfast of bad to non-existent support for standards.

Comment: @PaulTomblin, Well, if you stick to **only** things in the SQL standard, and you avoid syntax/performance features only specific to your db, then there would be no reason to switch database since **they would then all be the same**.

Comment: @Pacerier for reasons I've never quite understood, a lot of bosses trust Oracle more than they trust PostgreSQL. So I run PostgreSQL on my development/test server, and they deploy to an Oracle (or Sybase) server for UAT and production.

Comment: @PaulTomblin, Wow so aren't you basically limited to a very subset of queries that both Oracle and pgSQL support, and not just *support*, but  support **identically**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is no.

The long answer is that case-sensitivity for some things in MySQL depend on the underlying operating system. (Unix being the sensitive one)

Here is the reference to the issue in the [MySQL documentation.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

> Consequently, the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system plays a part in the case sensitivity of database and table names. This means database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of Unix. One notable exception is Mac OS X, which is Unix-based but uses a default file system type (HFS+) that is not case sensitive.

Also from the documentation on column names specifically:

> Column, index, and stored routine names are not case sensitive on any platform, nor are column aliases. Trigger names are case sensitive, which differs from standard SQL.

Comment: It also depends on the storage engine. MyISAM is dependent on the filesystem whereas InnoDB is not (unless you enable the "innodb_file_per_table" option if I'm not mistaken). And to make things even more complicated you also have the "lower_case_table_names" option

Comment: Database and table names are not column names. File system or OS case-sensitivity rules for file names do not apply in that case.

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking for case sensitivity.  It's fine if query "firstname" works for a column named "FirstName".  I just want to ensure that if I name the column "FirstName" in mysql, php will always read this column as "FirstName".  On Windows, folder names are not case sensitive per say, but you can specify a case.  For example, I can name a folder "MyFolder" and while I cannot create another folder named "myfolder", if I ever read the folder programmatically, it should always yield "MyFolder".

Comment: @Bryan - Your information on column names contradicts page 92 of the O'Reilly book MySQL and mSQL, which says database, table and column names are case sensitive.

Comment: Sorry Ian, I just double checked the documentation for all MySQL versions of 3, 4, and they also say "Column and index names are not case sensitive on any platform, nor are column aliases." My above excerpt is from the 5.6 documentation.

Answer (score -1):

MySQL is case sensitive in table and column names, and case in-sensitive in keywords.

But note that Windows is only case preserving, and file names are table names. (If you work on table "SalesAccounts" when you meant "Salesaccounts" then it will read OK on Windows and fail on Linux.

You should be OK with what you want to do, but
  1) Test on Linux, 
  2) Test the tools you are using.